# Is switching an if-statement around bad practice?

Tags: if-statement

I can remember being told that having an if statement like `if(10 == $myVariable)` is a bad practice. However, why is this a bad practice and what is its name? (I can vaguely remember that it has a specific name).

Comment: It's "Yoda conditions".

Comment: Actually some vehemently think that it's good practice to do that in case you accidentally type `(10 = $myVariable)`, since that throws an error unlike `($myVariable = 10)`. This question is primarily opinion-based though.

Comment: and its done to prevent accidental assignments that always return true, if you were to leave off one of the `=`s.

Comment: @DCoder *[Yoda conditions](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)* it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [a post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/) on Jeff Atwood's blog [Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/), StackOverflow user [zneak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251153/zneak) calls this a *Yoda Condition*. The description is as follows:

> Using `if(constant == variable)` instead of `if(variable == constant)`, like `if(4 == foo)`. Because it's like saying "if blue is the sky" or "if tall is the man".

This refers to the Star Wars character [Yoda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda), who [always talks backwards](http://scifi.about.com/od/starwarsglossaryandfaq/a/SWAR_yoda-speak.htm).

As [exussum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281385/exussum) mentiones in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27130319/2261330), it's sometimes not regarded as a bad practice because it can avoid typo's.

Answer (score 11):

its good practice because of accidental typos

```
if (10 = $myVariable)
```

will not compile where as

```
if ($myVariable = 10)
```

will and make the if statement true, and also set $myVariable to 10

is a fairly easy to make, and hard to spot error.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Comment: How can you say it is good practice? If you read your cited wiki article carefully you will see also criticism and disadvantages. So this is really an opinion based answer and not very impartial.

Comment: I agree its an option, but most "good practise" based questions are. For example use of white space while programming adds needless bytes to  a file (criticism and disadvantage) Though I don't know any any maintained code which does not use whitespace. one persons good practise will always be another ones bad practise. Think of Golf programmers using whitespace is definitely a disadvantage

Comment: I agree with you but shouldn't you at least mention that critics too? So anyone can make his own decisions based on the facts and not on anyone others opinion? Just an suggestion because in your answer I can't see that it's just an opinion. For me as a reader I take it as hard facts if critics are left out.

Answer (score 4):

It can also be good practice in languages where accessing `null` can lead to a failure, such as Java. For example, the following is safe even if myVariable is `null`:

```
if ("foo".equals(myVariable)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Whereas the following will throw a `NullPointerException`:

```
if (myVariable.equals("foo")) {
    // Do something
}
```

If your coding standards require that the variable comes first, your code's made more verbose by the requirement for a not null check:

```
if (myVariable != null && myVariable.equals("foo")) {
    // Do something
}
```